# Raise event in different context

Tags: c#, events, web, windows-services

I have a web application and a windows service. I'm at website trying to send a message who's need to raise a event in the windows service.

I start the windows service like something like this:

```
 _services.OnNewMessageArrivedAtEngine += new IntermediateServices.Services.OnNewMessageArrivedHandler(PutMessageInQueue);
```

and I try to raise the event at a different context at web application....

```
 if (OnNewMessageArrivedAtEngine != null)
   {
     OnNewMessageArrivedAtEngine(outgoingMessage);
   }
```

The OnNewMessageArrivedAtEngine always come null because the different contexts....

I don't want to use windows queues.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So you've got two different processes, right? How are you *expecting* those processes to communicate?

Comment: That's the question! How can I put this to processes (windows service and website) communicating?

Answer (score 0):

your web app could expose a service and your windows service could invoke it when it is needed

you need "something"(Remoting/WCF/etc) to make communicate processes running into two different AppDomain (like in your case)